# Can I script Vim using Python?

Tags: vimscript-python

Vimscript looks somewhat similar to Python code.

Can Vim be integrated with high-level language interpreters, such as Python?

Comment: When you have read the documentation that @derobert points to, you may find [Jarrod Taylor's demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMAeYp8mX_M) of writing python plugins helpful. He also hosts a "plugin starter kit" at [his github](https://github.com/JarrodCTaylor). I don't use it, but I found reading the code and the project wiki pages to be instructive.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, vim can be built with several different language interpreters available. This is something you (or your distro) picked when compiling vim from source.

Available at least are Python (as you requested), Perl, Ruby, and Tcl. The vim documentation has details for each; the python one is in [`:help if_pyth.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_pyth.txt.html). That document has plenty of examples.

For reference, here are the ones for other languages:

- Perl: [`:help if_perl.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_perl.txt.html)
- Ruby: [`:help if_ruby.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_ruby.txt.html)
- Tcl: [`:help if_tcl.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_tcl.txt.html)
- Lua: [`:help if_lua.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_lua.txt.html)
- MzScheme: [`:help if_mzscheme.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_mzsch.txt.html) (It's called Racket now, but in Vim it's still called MzScheme for historical reasons).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can create routines with high level languages such as python, ruby, perl, among other.

To see what languages your vim supports:

```
vim --version
```